# Expecting the same results from these two CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

However testCase2 does not handles the exception and throws an error. Am I missing something? Sorry if I did, quite new to this.

```
@Test
public void testCase1() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (true) throw new RuntimeException();
        return "Promise";
    }).exceptionally((ex) -> {
        return "Fake Promise";
    }).get();
}

@Test
public void testCase2() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (true) throw new RuntimeException();
        return "Promise";
    });
    cf.exceptionally((ex) -> {
        return "Fake Promise";
    });
    cf.get();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However testCase2 does not handles the exception

Your `testCase2` did handled the exception, you can add extra `print` statement to check it.

The reason `testCase2` throws an Exception is that code:

```
cf.exceptionally((ex) -> {
        System.out.println("Fake Promise: " + System.nanoTime());
        return "Fake Promise";
    })
```

will return a new `CompletableFuture` but you just discard it, the variable `cf` in `cf.get` is still not registered with any exception handler. The code should be:

```
@Test
public void testCase2() throws Exception {
    CompletableFuture<String> cf = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
        if (true) throw new RuntimeException();
        return "Promise";
    });
    CompletableFuture<String> handledCf = cf.exceptionally((ex) -> {
        return "Fake Promise";
    });
    return handledCf.get();
}
```

Comment: Not a big deal, just some common mistake everybody makes while learning :-)